# Camera freezes after screen unlock

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm currently developing photo camera app and I'm having some trouble: if you lock screen and then unlock it, image freezes.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_main);

    //...

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(id.surfaceView);
    holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    holderCallback = new HolderCallback();
    holder.addCallback(holderCallback);
}
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    camera = Camera.open(CAMERA_ID);
}

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

(`CameraOverlay()` is the class which extends `SurfaceView` and implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback`.  - from the post with similar problem) 
I don't use `CameraOverlay` anywhere, do I have to create it just for resuming preview after unlocking screen.

I have searched through multiple posts on this subject but couldn't find any solution that works for me, please help. I'm just starting to develop for android.

Comment: Can you post the camera related calls that are in your onCreate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your other option. `onResume()` will be called every time the app is viewed again. The issue is that you're setting the preview callback to `null` in your `onPause()`, and then not fixing it in your `onResume()'.

So change your `onResume()` to this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    camera = Camera.open(CAMERA_ID);
    holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    holderCallback = new HolderCallback();
    holder.addCallback(holderCallback);
}
```

That should fix your issue. Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: You are so cool! But it did not work for me:( I don't know what's wrong, your answer looks so elegant.

Comment: @vkalit Can you update the code to show me where you initialize the camera in your onCreate please?

Comment: I didn't do that, do I have to?

Comment: @vkalit if you could, please do - I'm trying to find the answer for you!

Comment: I'm trying to add
camera = Camera.open(CAMERA_ID);
to onCreate but it doesn't compile. How should I initialize the camera?

Comment: @AlexK I am using Camera2 and my camera freezes after unlocking the screen after a few minutes. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

In case of camera, All camera initialization should be done in OnResume() and it should (SHOULD) be deinitialized and released in onPause() . Else when your app goes to background other apps will not be able to get the camera instance.

Also there are a set of things to be done to initialize camera

1) safely opening camera
2) setting proper preview and picture sizes
3) starting preview and initializing the callbacks

Please look at the sample app i have uploaded in github and use it as a reference
https://github.com/shrishmv/CameraTest

hope this helps

Regards,
Shrish

Comment: Dear @Shrish, thank you for your feedback, but the trouble is that I'm making not only simple but the simpliest possible camera, that shoots only square photos and it works. the only thing that's wrong is that it's freezing after screen unlock. If I use your method I will have to develop the whole thing from scratch. Could you please help with my particular situation? How should I change my onCreate, onResume or onPause methods to fix the problem?